# Spring Quartz scheduled task stops running after some time

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, timer, quartz-scheduler

I have a Quartz timer task running in a webapp.
The task checks the database every 10 seconds for new data in a particular table.

```
<bean id="triggerCheckEvents" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
<property name="jobDetail">
    <bean id="jobCheckEvents" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="checkEvents" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="execute" />
        <property name="concurrent" value="false" />
    </bean>
</property>
<property name="startDelay" value="${checkEvent.startDelay}" />
<property name="repeatInterval" value="${checkEvent.repeatDelay}" />
```

About every second day or so, the timer stops running. I am somewhat sure that it gets stuck while doing something in the database. However, restarting the database does not seem to have effect on restoring the normal functioning of the timer. No exceptions get thrown. So there is not stack trace.

While I am trying to find the root cause. I think, I/O problems are bound to occur in a long running process. So the proper solution to this problem is to have some kind of watchdog that would, say, kill the thread after a timeout, spawn a new tread and continue the timer as per schedule.

**Is there a way to terminate a scheduled task and create a new instance when the task fails to return within a specified time frame?**

> I am not trying to fix this particular error with the Database. Because tomorrow some other error may block the thread. I am looking for a high level solution that would just terminate the tread or do whatever
>   is needed to free up resources blocked by the hung timer thread and
>   create a fresh instance. Unexpected problems are inevitable in a long
>   running process. The right solution is not to study and fix numerous
>   individual problems as and when they show up, but to have a strategy
>   to restore normal function even when errors occur.

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: One quick tip - whenever you are saying 'some error', it is going to be hard for us to 'guess' and most likely we'll move on to questions with little bit more information. That said, is there a stack trace? can you take a thread dump when the timer is stuck? Are there multiple timers querying the same database? Is there a pattern in this behavior?

Comment: @sstan Yeah, I'll edit it to make it more clear.

Comment: @prabugp The point is that the exact error is not imporatant. I am not trying to fix this particular error with the Database. I am looking for a  high level solution that would just terminate the tread or do whatever is needed to free up resources blocked by the hung timer thread and create a fresh instance. Unexpected problems are inevitable in a long running process. The right solution is not to study and fix numerous individual problems as and when they show up, but to have a strategy to restore normal function even when errors occur.

Comment: Agreed that unexpected problems are inevitable. But when it happens every second day or so, it isn't quite unexpected. And even if we want to gracefully resume operation upon error, we still have to fix those errors or know when not to resume. 

That said, if there is an I/O failure (DB down/network connectivity gone), we can catch and continue (preferably after a delay). If it's a table locking issue, we can try a connection with timeout - there isn't going to be a one approach solves all solution. (unless you want catch `Throwable`  and resume no matter what happened).

Comment: There are not exceptions. There is no stack trace. I've been unable to reproduce the error in dev environment.  I am not a novice developer. I am very much interested in finding the the problem with the database. But that wold not be a generic solution.  Normally if things are stuck due to database locks etc, restating the DB server ensures that the connections break and then exceptions are thrown. Nothing of that sort is happening. I have also looked into database logs, locks etc. they were not of much help.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem where a task used to get blocked. One approach is: at each invocation of the task, do actual stuff in new thread and make task's thread to wait for new thread to complete (till max allowed time is exceeded). This way task will never get blocked.

```
    public void work(JobExecutionContext ctx) {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            doSomethingInNewThread();
        }
    }, "ThreadName-" + System.currentTimeMillis());
    t.start();
    try {
        t.join(maxAllowedTime);
        if (t.isAlive()) {
            logger.warn("Tasks child thread "
                    + t.getName()
                    + "is still alive, potential thread block.");
            //TBD - if needed, add logic to terminate child thread
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```